# What is the maximum number of parallel queries can be executed in Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

What are the maximum number of calls one can make to Parse DB through Parallel promises?

Ref for Parse Parallel Promises: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel

In my case, app will update the data of different rows of same DB table in parallel. I am trying to update the status of 'm' number employees in series + parallel (Max number of employees will be around 10000).

Comment: Thank you. Posted your comment as a answer. Hope, it will be helpful to many others.

Comment: I'll post my post as answer, so you can close the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are limitation on this, but keep in mind there's a 3 second timeout in place for beforeSave/afterSave methods and 7 seconds for Cloud Functions. Moreover, you can select 1000 records maximum for query

Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Posting one of the comments as the answer. The below information is helpful. Credits to 'Luca Laco'.

I don't think there are limitation on this, but keep in mind there's a 3 second timeout in place for beforeSave/afterSave methods and 7 seconds for Cloud Functions. Moreover, you can select 1000 records maximum for query.